# Optimization of regular expressions

Tags: regex

I m new in regular expressions and I would like to know if there is any possibility to join and search together for strings like `.*1234oeoe.*` and `.*1234iaia.*`.

I would like to combine them in a way such that the word search for is `1234w` where `w` is either `oeoe` or `iaia`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use | operator:

```
1234(oeoe|iaia)
```